# Получить список файлов в папке с ресурсами

Tags: java, maven, resources

Пытаюсь получить список файлов из папки с ресурсами. Все работает в IDE. Однако когда собираю jar файл.Он не видит никаких файлов

```
   InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("colormaps");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    return br.lines()
            .map(line -> PATH_TO_COLORMAPS_IMAGES + "colormaps/" + line.replace("json", "png"))
            .collect(toList());
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким способом соответственно выдает ошибку во время исполнения Jar

```
File dir = new File(path); //path указывает на директорию
File[] arrFiles = dir.listFiles();
List<File> lst = Arrays.asList(arrFiles);
```

Полная структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы попробуйте указать в коде путь не как `colormaps`, а как `resources/colormaps` (можете еще `/resources/colormaps` попробовать) и собрать `jar`. Если заработает, помогу с пониманием сего) И да, хотелось бы, чтобы вы показали полную иерархию проекта, ибо все зависит от того, что в каких пакетах находится

Comment: К сожалению, не заработало. Jar собирается с помощью maven. Может в этом какая-то проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код предназначен для работы с файлами, но ресурсы - это не совсем файлы, внутри jar-файла у вас нет привычной файловой системы. Попробуйте так:

```
try(JarFile jar = new JarFile(new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain()
                                                 .getCodeSource()
                                                 .getLocation()
                                                 .getPath()))) {
    jar.stream()
       .map(JarEntry::getName)
       .filter(i -> i.startsWith("colormaps/"))
       .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Ну я попробовал и этот код, и тот. Ничего. Т.е. я запускаю из консоли jar и у меня ничего не выводится. Хотя все остальные ресурсы к которым конкретно прописан путь, работают нормально.

Comment: Попробуем подойти к вопросу с другой стороны. Исправил.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо за помощь)