# Извлечь папку из корня программы

Tags: java

Для извлечения одного или нескольких файлов я использую конструкцию вроде такой:

```
    InputStream input_stream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/someExampleFolder/someExampleFIle1.txt");
    FileOutputStream output_stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "test.txt"));
    while (input_stream.available() > 0) {
        output_stream.write(input_stream.read());
    }
```

Но если надо извлечь всю папку, то прописывать такое для всех файлов в папке долго, поэтому вопрос такой, как можно извлечь папку из программы, ну или все файлы в папке?

Comment: Получить список файлов в папке и обойти их в цикле, применяя ваш код на каждой итерации.

Comment: А как получить список всех файлов в папке?

Comment: Папка на диске или в jar-файле?

Comment: Папка в jar-файле

Comment: Тогда вам может помочь [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/805862/204271).

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, то что нужно!